# pyspark where to import unpackArray from?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing the course [UCSanDiegoX: DSE230x](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UCSanDiegoX+DSE230x+1T2018/course/) on edx. In the part about user defined functions this code is used:

```
def count_nan(V):
    A = unpackArray(V, data_type=np.float16)
    return int(sum(np.isnan(A)))

Count_nan_udf = udf(count_nan, IntegerType())
```

Though they don't explain where this functions are comming from, i.e. how to import them into the namespace.

I found udf here:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
```

And `IntegerType`:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
```

Though I don't find `unpackArray`. Do I need to import it at all?

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `IntegerType` (no r before the g). You can import it from  `pyspark.sql.types`

Comment: Thanks, that explains, why I did not find it there.

Comment: I changed the issue to address the import of unpackArray.

Comment: It seems like it comes from somewhere else in that course. But why does it matter? It's pretty obvious what `count_nan` does- just write some code to count the `nan` values in `V`.

Answer (score 1):

I am also taking the same course. packArray() and unpackArray() are user defined functions which have been defined in lib/numpy_pack.py file.

packArray() is used to pack a numpy array to a bytearray to be stored as a single field in a spark dataframe. unpackArray() is the reversed operation.